# Autodesk Forge wrench sample project

Tags: autodesk-forge

After downloading the web app project, a ipt will load but iam files indicate the model is empty - after translation. I opened the model in Inventor and created a copy just to test.

Comment: It seems like you're missing references on your model.

Please, refer to our tutorials on adding references:
 https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/
 https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-containing-xref/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.